# Best way to access read-only database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord, master-slave

Our app is deployed on Heroku with Unicorn and master-slave database configuration with all app requests (read and write) going to master DB.

What we need is to redirect some of the `read` traffic to follower (slave) database.

For achieving this, we added `read_only_database_connection.rb` -

```
class ReadOnlyDatabaseConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

and added a mixin `switch_connection.rb`

```
module SwitchConnection
  def readonly_db_connection    
    current_conf = ReadOnlyDatabaseConnection.connection_config
    begin
      ReadOnlyDatabaseConnection.establish_connection(READONLY_CONFIG).tap do
        puts "Primary DB -> Follower DB"
      end

      yield
    ensure
      ReadOnlyDatabaseConnection.establish_connection(current_conf).tap do
        puts "Follower DB -> Primary DB"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then in `application_controller.rb`, I did -

```
include SwitchConnection
around_filter :readonly_db_connection, only: [:index, :show]
```

Is this the right way to do this? Is there any better or safer approach to redirect all `show` and `index` traffic to readonly database?

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus

Answer (score 5):

I think objects that inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` should be responsible for dealing with the database. You can have models that check the read-only slave database.

```
class ReadOnlyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection 'readonly_db'

  def readonly?
    true
  end
end

class Controller
  def index
    @models = ReadOnlyModel.all
  end
end

# in config/database.yml
readonly_database:
  adapter: #...
```

If you want to use the same table names (which I suspect you do), you can use the [table_name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/table_name/class) method.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ReadOnlyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name :models
end
```

Here's the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/readonly%3F) for the `readonly?` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have more than 100 models and I would not like to replicate those as readonly models.

Comment: an IMPORTANT caveat is that if you use update_column on a table with readonly? set this way, the database WILL be written

Comment: As a best practice is also good to create a read only user on the database side.